# How to place $k$ objects in $P$ boxes, such that many objects can be placed in one box

Tags: combinatorics

Given $P$ boxes, how many ways are there to place $k$ indistinguishable objects, $k\leq P,$ whereby you can place from $0$ up to $k$ objects in each container. The result should be $C^{k+P-1}_{k},$ which I can eventually prove by induction.

What I don't understand is the way this result is established. Can somebody provide an explanation to derive the result?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_i$ be the number of objects in box $i$ with $i=1,\dots ,P$. Then we have to count the number of **non negative** integer solutions, i.e. $x_i\geq 0$, of
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{P-1}+x_P=k.$$
Which is the same (see [Stars and Bars Thm 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_2)) to place $P-1$ bars $|$ which divides a sequence of $k+P-1$ stars $\underbrace{\star\star\dots \star\star}_{k+P-1}$ into $P$ blocks:
$$ \binom{k+P-1}{P-1}=\binom{k+P-1}{k}.$$
A similar reasoning works when we have to count the number of **positive** integer solutions, i.e. $x_i\geq 1$, (see [Stars and Bars Thm 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one_2)) which is given by
$$\binom{k-1}{P-1}.$$

P.S. I recommend also the Numberphile's video [Stars and Bars (and bagels)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTCScjoPymA).

Answer (score 1):

This is the supermarket principle:

Consider $k+P-1$ objects lining in a line. Choose $k$ of them as 'dividers'. Then there is a bijection between the objects and dividers with the number of objects in each box.